# mariadb not using all fields of composite index

Tags: indexing, mariadb, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, composite-key

Mariadb not fully using composite index. Fast select and slow select both return same data, but explain shows that slow select uses only ix_test_relation.entity_id part and does not use ix_test_relation.stamp part.

I tried many cases (inner join, with, from) but couldn't make mariadb use both fields of index together with recursive query. I understand that I need to tell mariadb to materialize recursive query somehow.

Please help me optimize slow select which is using recursive query to be similar speed to fast select.

Some details about the task... I need to query user activity. One user activity record may relate to multiple entities. Entities are hierarchical. I need to query user activity for some parent entity and all children for specified stamp range. Stamp simplified from TIMESTAMP to BIGINT for demonstration simplicity. There can be a lot (1mil) of entities and each entity may relate to a lot (1mil) of user activity entries. Entity hierarchy depth expected to be like 10 levels deep. I assume that used stamp range reduces number of user activity records to 10-100. I denormalized schema, copied stamp from test_entry to test_relation to be able to include it in test_relation index.

I use 10.4.11-Mariadb-1:10:4.11+maria~bionic.
I can upgrade or patch or whatever mariadb if needed, I have full control over building docker image.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test_entity(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  parent_id BIGINT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_test_entity PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_test_entity_pid FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES test_entity(id)
);
CREATE TABLE test_entry(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  stamp BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_test_entry PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE test_relation(
  entry_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  entity_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  stamp BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_test_relation PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, entity_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_test_relation_erid FOREIGN KEY (entry_id) REFERENCES test_entry(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_test_relation_enid FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES test_entity(id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_relation ON test_relation(entity_id, stamp);
CREATE SEQUENCE sq_test_entry;
```

Test data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_insert()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_entry_id BIGINT;
  DECLARE v_parent_entity_id BIGINT;
  DECLARE v_child_entity_id BIGINT;
  FOR i IN 1..1000 DO
    SET v_parent_entity_id = i * 2;
    SET v_child_entity_id = i * 2 + 1;
    INSERT INTO test_entity(id, parent_id)
    VALUES(v_parent_entity_id, NULL);
    INSERT INTO test_entity(id, parent_id)
    VALUES(v_child_entity_id, v_parent_entity_id);
    FOR j IN 1..1000000 DO
      SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR sq_test_entry
      INTO v_entry_id;
      INSERT INTO test_entry(id, name, stamp)
      VALUES(v_entry_id, CONCAT('entry ', v_entry_id), j);
      INSERT INTO test_relation(entry_id, entity_id, stamp)
      VALUES(v_entry_id, v_parent_entity_id, j);
      INSERT INTO test_relation(entry_id, entity_id, stamp)
      VALUES(v_entry_id, v_child_entity_id, j);
    END FOR;
  END FOR;
END;
CALL test_insert;
```

Slow select (> 100ms):

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM test_relation TR
WHERE TR.entity_id IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE recursive_child AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM test_entity
    WHERE id IN (2, 4)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT C.id
    FROM test_entity C
    INNER JOIN recursive_child P
    ON P.id = C.parent_id
  )
  SELECT id
  FROM recursive_child
)
AND TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

Fast select (1-2ms):

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM test_relation TR
WHERE TR.entity_id IN (2,3,4,5)
AND TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

UPDATE 1

I can demonstrate the problem with even shorter example.

Explicitly store required entity_id records in temporary table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl
WITH RECURSIVE recursive_child AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM test_entity
  WHERE id IN (2, 4)
    
  UNION ALL
    
  SELECT C.id
  FROM test_entity C
  INNER JOIN recursive_child P
  ON P.id = C.parent_id
)
SELECT id
FROM recursive_child
```

Try to run select using temporary table (below). Select is still slow but the only difference with fast query now is that IN statement queries table instead of inline constants.

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM test_relation TR
WHERE TR.entity_id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl)
AND TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

Comment: I thought about switching composite index to stamp, entity_id, but in this case index would correspond to O(n) instead of O(1) in relation to number of entities. Meaning this query would slow down with increase of entities, which should not happen

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: If `stamp` is a `TIMESTAMP`, leave it as such.  `BETWEEN 6 AND 8` smells like `IN(6,7,8)`, which is not likely to occur with a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: It won't hurt to have _both_ (stamp, entity_id) and (entity_id, stamp) -- That way the optimizer can _dynamically_ pick between them based on the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

For your queries (both of them) it looks to me like you should, as you mentioned, flip the column order on your compound index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test_relation ON test_relation(stamp, entity_id);
```

Why?

Your queries have a range filter `TR.stamp BETWEEN 2 AND 3` on that column. For a range filter to use an index range scan (whether on a `TIMESTAMP` or a `BIGINT` column), the column being filtered must be *first* in a multicolumn index.

You also want a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) filter, that is something lik this:

```
    TR.stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND TR.stamp <  CURDATE()
```

in place of

```
    DATE(TR.stamp) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE(NOW())
```

That is, don't put a function on the column you're scanning in your WHERE clause.

With a structured query like your first one, the query planner turns it into several queries.  You can see this with `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON`.  The planner may choose different indexes and/or different chunks of indexes for each of those subqueries.

And, a word to the wise: don't get too wrapped around the axle trying to outguess the query planner built into the DBMS. It's an extraordinarily complex and highly wrought piece of software, created by decades of programming work by world-class experts in optimization. Our job as MariaDB / MySQL users is to find the right indexes.

Comment: As I mentioned the problem with (stamp,entity_id) index is that it's O(n), not O(1). Basically you query ALL entities for user activity in specified date range. The problem is that when number of entities grow, this index usage will degrade in performance. Let's say we have 1 mil entities each generated 3 records of user activity during last week. To fetch 9 records for 3 entities DB would scan 3 mil records in this index.

Comment: And I can't just ignore this problem because I need to implement requirements with code that uses 1% of DBMS and run in milliseconds compared to 100% CPU and several seconds for one lousy user activity query which is not even business critical

Comment: About sargabling... I'm well aware about this problem and as you may see I don't have any functions or other type of conversions in my example. I used BIGINT field type just to simplify example. I use timestamp(3) field for my real code

Answer (score 1):

The order of columns in a composite index matters.  (O.Jones explains it nicely -- using SQL that has been removed from the Question?!)

I would rewrite

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM test_relation TR
WHERE TR.entity_id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl)
AND TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

as

```
SELECT TR.entry_id
    FROM tbl
    JOIN test_relation TR  ON tbl.id = TR.entity_id
    WHERE TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

or

```
SELECT entry_id
    FROM test_relation TR
    WHERE TR.stamp BETWEEN 6 AND 8
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl
                       WHERE tbl.id = TR.entity_id )
```

And have these in either case:

```
TR: INDEX(stamp, entity_id, entry_id)  -- With `stamp` first
tbl: INDEX(id) -- maybe
```

Since `tbl` is a freshly built TEMPORARY TABLE, and it seems that only 3 rows need checking, it may not be worth adding `INDEX(id)`.

Also needed:

```
test_entity:  INDEX(parent_id, id)
```

Assuming that `test_relation` is a many:many mapping table, it is likely that you will also need (though not necessarily for the current query):

```
INDEX(entity_id, entry_id)
```

Comment: I've tried those, didn't work. you may try yourself and see

Comment: @user1194528 - Please provide the exact `SHOW CREATE TABLE` that "didn't work".  A rule that I failed to mention:  If you have _both_ `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, the Optimizer _may_ pick the former when the latter would actually be better.  So, Drop the former.